# Sizeof in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Size of character ('a') in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()                
{  
    printf("%d" , sizeof('a'));  
    return 0;  
}

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;     

int main(){  
  cout << sizeof('a');  
  return 0;  
}
```

For C, it gives 4 as answer whereas for C++ it gives 1 ?
My question is why the languages interpret the character constant differently ?

Comment: Something interesting (though perhaps not very useful) is you can legally refer to something like 'abcd' (single quotes rather than double)... it doesn't define a char or a string of chars, it defines an int whose value is based on the ascii values of each char strung together.

Comment: Probably and ansi vs. unicode thing, but thats a guess

Comment: The rules I'm familiar with are the exact opposite (`sizeof('a')` is 4 in C and 1 in C++).

Comment: This question has already been answered [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c); use the search before asking a question! :)

Comment: … Hmm, clicking "ask question" and pasting the text of this there instantly shows that as the first "similar question." No need to click search at all.

Comment: Another good thread to look at is this : [sizeof taking two arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331588/sizeof-taking-two-arguments)

Comment: new to the site....don't know its features yet

Comment: @mah: It was useful in the old days when apple did company ids as 4 characters (you had to register with apple). Your company ID (4 char) was then encoded as an int int resource part of the application. `companyId = 'appl';` This way it was easy to covert the int ID into a human readable ID any you could guess the company from the ID without looking it up in a big DB.

Answer (score 4):

Actually `sizeof('a') == sizeof(int)` in C (so you should get `4`). I'm not **entirely sure** about C++ but I believe `sizeof('a') == sizeof(char)`.

The C part is explained in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/charstring/sizeofchar.html).

> Perhaps surprisingly, character
>   constants in C are of type `int`, so
>   `sizeof('a')` is `sizeof(int)` (though
>   **this is another area where C++
>   differs**)

Answer (score 0):

You have managed to find one of the few places where the C and C++ standards differ significantly. They are different answers because the specs say they must be.