# Strange case while using the sizeof() operator in C

Tags: c, sizeof

I was testing the use of sizeof operator in C/C++ with this code:

```
#include <ctype.h>              /* Character types                       */
#include <stdio.h>              /* Standard buffered input/output        */
#include <stdlib.h>             /* Standard library functions            */
#include <string.h>             /* String operations                     */
#include <sys/types.h>          /* Data types                            */
#include <sys/wait.h>           /* Declarations for waiting              */
#include <unistd.h>   

void main()
{
  char a[100];
  char *des = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
  strcpy(des,"abcded\0");
  printf("%d\n",sizeof(des));
  printf("%d\n",sizeof(a));
  free(des);
}
```

Why does this program output:

```
4
100
```

As opposed to:

```
100
100
```

Comment: Because you haven't read the [comp.lang.c faq](http://c-faq.com/) ... Start with section 6 :)

Comment: It's `int main`; C is not Java.

Comment: @Jens people have been mis-typing `main` as `void` since long before Java was around. It's wrong, but there's no reason to mention Java at all, really.

Answer (score 4):

Because, *despite the assertions of many people*, pointers and arrays are NOT 100% interchangeable in C & C++.  This is a clear example of one of the differences.

The size of a pointer is 4-bytes (or whatever platform specific size), regardless of how much allocated memory it may point to.

The size of an array is the size of the array.

Comment: Memory is not "allocated to [the pointer]". The reason I'm highlighting this poor wording in your answer is that this same erroneous view of pointers is probably responsible for OP's question in the first place.

Comment: Revised my answer to clarify the relation (or lack of relation) between pointers and allocations.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(des)` returns the size of the pointer - which is 4 on your system. It doesn't return the size of the allocated space it points to.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%d\n",sizeof(des));
printf("%d\n",sizeof(a));
```

is equivalent to the following:

```
printf("%d\n",sizeof(char*));      //prints size of a pointer
printf("%d\n",sizeof(char[100]));  //size of a char array of size 100
```

In other words, `sizeof` is an operator which operates *on the type* of the expression which you passed to it. So when you write `sizeof(des)` the *type* of the expression is `char*`, hence it prints `sizeof(char*)` which is `4` on your system. But in case of `sizeof(a)`, the type of the expression is `char[100]`, hence it prints `sizeof(char[100])` which is `100`.

A more interesting case with `sizeof` is discussed here:

- [sizeof taking two arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331588/sizeof-taking-two-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Because it returns the size of the pointer *des* which points to the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof` operator yields the no. of bytes for a type.

`sizeof des` gives 100, because the type of `des` is a `char[100]`, a char always takes 1 byte, and there's 100 of them.

`sizeof a` gives 4 because the type of `a` is a `char*`, and a char pointer takes 4 bytes on your platform (which is typical on 32 bit platforms.)

So, sizeof just works on the type of it's operand (note, sizeof is an operator, it is not a function/macro). sizeof does not interact with malloc, and the fact that  `a` points to the start of 100 dynamically allocated bytes is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I'll elaborate slightly upon abelenky's comment.  Do you expect these two typedefs to product equivalent types?

```
typedef char *string;
typedef char string[100];
```

How about these two?

```
typedef struct { char *s; ... } header_t;
typedef struct { char s[100]; ... } header_t;
```

Your answer is clearly no in both cases. Yes, you could compile `des=a` because `a` yields a pointer, but `a` is actually an array.

In particular, you also know this last typedef reserves no memory for a pointer.  As a result,  `a` has roughly the type `char * const` meaning `a` is a constant pointer to non-constant characters, and thus `a=des` gives a type error.  I donno if said error message will complain about arrays, `const`, or an lvalue though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is very simple.

The type of des is "char *" or the address of a character. So the question you are asking the compiler by using sizeof is "How much memory (in bytes) do I need to store the address of a character?" The compiler responds 4 because your program and compiler has 32bit (4 bytes) addressing. When you use sizeof on an array you are asking a different question which is "How much memory (in bytes) do I need to store a character array of 100 items?" The answer here is 100 items * 1 byte = 100 bytes.