# Uncertain output of this C code

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)
>   [Why does sizeof(x++) not increment x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225776/why-does-sizeofx-not-increment-x)

Here the value of `i` is 5 but it should be 6 or 7 I guess. What's the reason?

```
int main(void){
    int i=5,j;
    j=sizeof(i++ + ++i);
    printf("%d %d",i,j);
}
```

Comment: For your pleasure: [why not to use `void main`](http://stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main)

Comment: I think this was closed for the wrong reason. Although `i++ + ++i` is undefined behaviour when evaluated, it is not evaluated here, since it's the argument of `sizeof`. Since the type of the expression is `int`, the line `j=sizeof(i++ + ++i);` sets `j` to `sizeof(int)` and does not modify `i`.