# sizeof operator doesn't evaluate the subexpression?

Tags: c, operators, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does sizeof(x++) not increment x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225776/why-does-sizeofx-not-increment-x)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  double num=5.2;
  int var=5;
  printf("%d\t",sizeof(!num));
  printf("%d\t",sizeof(var=15/2));
  printf("%d",var);
  return 0;
}
```

The program gave an output `4 4 5`. I didn't quite get why this happened.

- Why was the first output 4?
- Why didn't the value of `var` get updated to 7?

How does the `sizeof` operator work?

Comment: while i accept my question happened to be a duplicate of another question on SO, a more appropriate heading to the other question and I might have never put up the question. Didn't turn up in search. Anyways thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expressions

```
!num
var=15/2
```

both evaluate to an int.  `sizeof(int)` is always 4 on your platform.

As for why var is not updated:

> sizeof is a compile-time operator, so at the time of compilation sizeof and its operand get replaced by the result value. The operand is not evaluated (except when it is a variable length array) at all; only the type of the result matters.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8225813/141172

Comment: how come `var` is not updated??

Comment: @sasidhar: Look at the comment by Mystical under your question.

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof` operator shows you the size of the darts *type* of its argument. It does not return the result of the argument. On your platform an integer is 4 bytes long, that's what you learn here. If you want the result, just cut out the `sizeof`.