# increment operator not working with sizeof

Tags: c++, operators, sizeof

Just wondering why the increment operator is not working in the below code snippet:

```
    int main()
    {
        int a = 10;
        int b = sizeof(a++);
        cout<<"a: "<<a<<endl;
        cout<<"b: "<<b<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Output-

a: 10

b: 4

Comment: Sizeof is a compile-time operator, and the entire sizeof() gets replaced with its resultant value before compiling the code.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225776/why-does-sizeofx-not-increment-x/8225813#8225813

Comment: What is the expected behavior for that code?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: I guess the asker's expectation is a=11, b=10.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sizeof` does not evaluate its argument. It calculates the argument's size statically at compile-time without causing any code to be executed.

Comment: Why am I surprised by this?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Because you don't know C++?

Comment: @sbi Yeah, that's a likely cause

Comment: So I have a doubt, if it doesnot evaluate the argument expression why it is throwing error if I declare that variable a as a constant ?

Answer (score 8):

When the type of the expression to sizeof is not a variably modified array type, then the expression is not evaluated because the type is completely known at compile time. `int` has no variably modified parts.

In C++ (up to at least C++11) there are no variably modified types (at least not as in the concept of C - you can argue that `new int[a++]` uses a variably modified array type; but the type does not escape to any other part of the language. In particular, not to `sizeof`), so in C++, the expression to sizeof is never evaluated. In C, it is unspecified whether an expression is evaluated if it doesn't influence the size of a variably modified array type. For example

```
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = sizeof(int[a++ ? 1 : 1]);
    cout<<"a: "<<a<<endl;
    cout<<"b: "<<b<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In C (from C99 onwards), this may output `11` for `a`, but it may also output `10`, depending on whether the compiler is clever enough to omit evaluating `a++`, deducing that the sizeof `int[10]` is computed at compile time.

---

Footnote: Variably modified array types are also called VLA (variable length array) types. In short, a variably modified type is a type that is either a VLA type or a type that depends on one. For example `int(*)[a++]`.

Comment: +1: in C++11, 5.3.3p1, "The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand. The operand is either an expression, **which is an unevaluated operand** (Clause 5), or a parenthesized type-id." emphasis added.

Answer (score 2):

The operand of the `sizeof` operator is unused, it's not evaluated. This is standard behavior.

Comment: But `a` is used both to determine `sizeof(a++)` and later for output.

Answer (score 1):

sizeof is not a function in C.

Its argument is not really evaluated, only its type is and this is done at compile-time.
In your code, the assignment is equivalent (in your architecture) to :

```
int b = 4
```

Comment: "this is done at runtime. " -- really?

Answer (score 0):

In an *unevaluated-context*, only the type matters. The same happens when calling functions:

```
void f();

sizeof(f()); // f not called
```