# Array allocation in C++ on stack with varying length

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, clang

I was surprised to find out that it is possible to allocate an varying-length array on the stack in C++  (such as `int array[i];`). It seems to work fine on both clang and gcc (on OS/X) but MSVC 2012 don't allow it.

What is this language feature called? And is it an official C++ language feature? If yes, which version of C++?

Full example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int sum(int *array, int length){
    int s = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<length;i++){
        s+= array[i];
    }
    return s;
}

int func(int i){
    int array[i]; // <-- This is the feature that I'm talking about
    for (int j=0;j<i;j++){
        array[j] = j;
    }

    return sum(array, i);

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << "Func 1 "<<func(1)<<endl;
    cout << "Func 2 "<<func(2)<<endl;
    cout << "Func 3 "<<func(3)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the current standard, this is not allowed. It is a compiler extension called *variable length arrays*. With suitable compilation flags, your code would fail to compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking at GCC's [variable length arrays](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html). That's a GNU extension and is not standard C++.

Comment: I think it is proper adding that this should not be used since it will not compile by other compilers.

Answer (score 6):

This feature is called *Variable Length Arrays* or VLAs.

It's part of C99 standard (and also C11) but is not supported by C++11. However, as you see some compilers accept it as an extension.

Finally, a similar feature (but not exactly the same as C99's VLAs) was approved at the C++ committee meeting in Bristol (April 2013) and is in the [current draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf) of C++14.

Two main differences between C99's VLAs and C++14's are illustrated below:

```
void f(std::size_t n) {
    int a[n];
    unsigned int x = sizeof(a);
    // ...
    int matrix m[n][n];
}
```

In C99, the expression `sizeof(a)` is evaluated at runtime. In C++14 this is illegal. In addition, multidimensional VLAs are not supported by C++14.

For more information on C99's VLAs see [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-cwhy-variable-length-arrays/184401444) DrDobb's article.

For more information on C++14's runtime-sized arrays see [N3639](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3639.html), the paper that was approved in Bristol.

**Update:** In the Chigago meeting, the committee decided to remove this feature from C++14 and instead put it in a separate document, a [Technical Specification (TS) on array Extendions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3820.html) (TS). In addition, the TS also includes the template class `dynarray` which is somewhat related to arrays of runtime bounds.

The main reason it was dropped from C++14 is that the committee wants to get feedback from implementation and user experience before standardizing these features.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [`gcc` extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions) and it seems like [`clang supports this in limited cases`](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla) it is not standard C++ although it is [valid `c99`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588265/why-am-i-being-allowed-to-use-a-const-qualified-variable-as-an-array-size-in-c). In `gcc` and `clang` you can use the `-pedantic` flag it will give you a warning like this in `gcc`:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘array’ [-Wvla]
```

and like this in `clang`:

```
warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `constexpr` (C++11) as a workaround in some situations:

```
constexpr int getArraySize (int factor) {
    return 2 * factor + 1;
}

int my_array[getArraySize(3)];
```

Actually in C++14, this limitation shouldn't be there any more: http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/04/n3639-runtime-sized-arrays-with-automatic-storage-duration