# Dynamic Array using const int

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

This is also a valid code to declare dynamic arrays.

`malloc` needs pointers, this doesn't. Is this a better method?

```
 printf("enter the size of array")
 scanf("%d",&x)
 const int size
 size = x
 int array[size]
```

Comment: As far I know, VLA are exactly as `malloc()` at run-time. Also, why do you think that pointers are bad? note that you're using VLA, that's a valid code according to C99 standard only.

Comment: That code won't compile, even if you add the missing semicolons.

Comment: As @TomTanner said this won't compile, so no this isn't a better method.

Comment: the code is working properly. array can be created and used like that.

Comment: Example code that compiles without modification usually get a better reception on SO, i.e. having to add `;` and fixing reassignment to `const` variables which is not legal etc... ideally it should be a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @user2653718 No it cannot. `int main(){ const int test; test =1;}` When compiled: `t.c:7: error: assignment of read-only variable "test"`

Comment: There are several online compilers available from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator if you don't have one currently available and as far as I know they all support C as well as C++.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x,i;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    const int n=x;
    int array[n];
    for( i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

     array[i]=i;
    printf("%d",array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

Comment: @user2653718 Posting code edits in the comment is not readable, you can just edit your question and replace the existing code.

Comment: in some compilers it works but on some it says segmentation fault or runtime error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say if one is better than the other, a better question would be what are the advantages of each, you need to decided based on your requirements but using `malloc` and using variable length arrays(`VLA`) are not the same.

There are some major differences.`1)` A VLA will usually be allocated on the stack although that is an implementation decision, the standard just says there are `automatic`. The stack is more limited than the the heap which is where a `malloc`'ed array will go and so you can easily overflow your stack. `2)` You need to free a `malloc`'ed array a VLA is an automatic variable and will not exist outside of the scope it is declared in. `3)` VLA is part of the [`C99 standard`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588265/why-am-i-being-allowed-to-use-a-const-qualified-variable-as-an-array-size-in-c) and so code using `VLA` will not be [portable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246900/enabling-vlasvariable-length-arrays-in-ms-visual-c).