# C++ array size declaration and const

Tags: c++, c, arrays, c++11, constants

I'm just jumping into C++, coming from C

In C (89/90), a `const` is not actually a constant (as opposed to a `#define`'d, `enum`, or literal), but rather  read-only once set. I.e, I can:

```
const int x = rand();
```

and that's fine - the point being `x` isn't known until runtime. Hence, I can't

```
int arr[x]; // error - x is not a compile-time constant
```

Then, one of the C standards (99?) went ahead and allowed for variable-length arrays. Although I normally code against the ANSI standard in C, this has actually had an impact now that I am trying to pickup C++11.

As far as I know, C++ does not allow for variable-length arrays. However, many compilers allow it as an extension (GCC ?). The problem is, now that I am trying to learn C++11, I can't tell if what I'm coding is valid C++, or C++ extended with C99-compatibility. Ex:

```
std::default_random_engine e{};
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d{};
const int x{d(e)};
int arr[x]; // compiles
```

I can't tell if this is valid C++ or not. Clearly, the value of `x` is not known until runtime. I think I may not understand the difference between C and C++ `const`?

Comment: Not valid. Use flags `-std=...` where `...` is a standard, e.g. `c++11` or `c++98`.

Comment: You may also use `-pedantic`

Comment: @juanchopanza I actually did compile using `-std=c++11` and clang produced no warnings. Using the `-pedantic` flag as Shafik suggested made the warnings pop up!

Comment: Not valid in C++11, but C++14 allows stack arrays with runtime sizes

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, The Array Extensions TS didn't make it into C++14.

Comment: @chris someone is looking out for us

Comment: As was mentioned, you **can* make variable-sized array, using `int* arr = new int[x];`, and `delete[] arr;` when `arr` is no longer needed, or, better, using [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: This is somewhat related question: [Does “int size = 10;” yield a constant expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21273829/1708801) which may be interesting since my answer to that question goes into details about what is considered an integral constant expression. Which is what an array bound requires.

Comment: @chris do you mean that the "array extensions TS" covers the runtime sizes array? I am looking into 8.3.4 of a 2013 draft (n3690) and it talks about "array of runtime bound of T". Isn't that the thing I was talking about?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, As I recall, they were in, but got pulled out. I don't see them in N3797 at all. There's a [Rapperswil trip report](http://botondballo.wordpress.com/2014/07/17/trip-report-c-standards-committee-meeting-in-rapperswil-june-2014/) that has more information on its status.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct [VLAs are a C99 feature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16588265/1708801)(*optional in C11*) and the C++ standard does not include this feature although both `gcc` and `clang` allow them in C++ as an extension. We can see they are not allowed by going to the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) section `8.3.4` *Arrays* which says:

```
D1 [ constant-expressionopt] attribute-specifier-seqopt
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

For both `gcc` and `clang` using the `-pedantic` flag will warn when you are using an extension. If you are targeting C++11 then you should also specify that using `-std=c++11`. You can use `-pedantic-errors` to turn the warning into errors. If you compile your code using `-pedantic` you should see the the following warning:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'arr' [-Wvla]
int arr[x]; // compiles
         ^
```

`gcc` documents their support for various standards, defaults and flags to enforce standard on their [Language Standards Supported by GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html#Standards) page and it says:

> to obtain all the diagnostics required by the standard, you should
>   also specify -pedantic (or -pedantic-errors if you want them to be
>   errors rather than warnings).

In general `clang` supports what `gcc` does but you can find more details on their [Language Compatibility](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html) page.

Note as mentioned by GingerPlusPlus [std:vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is considered the alternative for VLA in C++.

Comment: marvellous!! So it seems that this *is* using the C99 extension