# How can I compile only standard C++ with GNU g++?

Tags: c++, g++

There are some extensions in the GNU g++ compilers such as VLA (variable length arrays), even though those features are not C++ standards.

So if I need to compile a program using only C++ standard constructs and avoiding those extra extensions, can I do it with GNU g++?

Something like `g++ test.cpp -std=onlyStandards`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2855121/390913

Comment: See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25939282/1708801), in short you want `-std=c++11 -pedantic-errors` where c++11 is replaced with the standard you want to conform to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ array size declaration and const](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25939260/c-array-size-declaration-and-const)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass the `-pedantic-errors` flag. Be sure to set a standard with `-std=`, such as `-std=c++14`. This works in clang as well.

Comment: No, GCC's flags are not standardized.

Comment: Indeed, but a lot of them are common with Clang.