# Array declaration inside a function

Tags: c, arrays, variable-length-array

Is it safe to write code like below?

```
void func(int v[], int size) {
 int array_local[size];

 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) array_local[i] = v[i];

 /*
 Other stuff...
 */

}
```

Or could I stumble upon some kind of error?

Comment: Depends on what you do and also on the value of `size`. Nothing in the given code is wrong though.

Comment: Note, that variable length arrays are stored on the stack and you have limited stack space so this case be an issue. Also note if you want the code code to be portable [VLA is a C99 feature](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16588397/1708801) and [until recently Visual Studio did not support C99](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27826409/1708801) and as far as I know variable length arrays are still missing.

Comment: It is OK in C99, as long as the size is small enough not to overflow the stack. You would be better off with `size` of type `size_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah this is perfectly fine and valid on and above `C99`. It is called [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

To be on safer side, you should put a check on the value of `size` before using it as the number of elements of the array. As you've got the `size` defined as `int`, you should prohibit passing a value of  say `-5` to `size`.

That said, for the remaining part of the code (as a general suggestion)

1. `v[i]` should not cause in memory overrun.
2. The array is local to the function. You should never try returning the *address* of the array (Either through a pointer or through `return` statement).

Comment: Could i potentially declare a double sized array, something like "int array_local[2*size]"?

Comment: @Lukkio yeah, certainly you can, provided 1) the suggested checks on `size` are done. and 2) the `2* size` does not cause stackoverflow.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is safe as long as the caller ensures that `v` has at least `size` elements, otherwise of course it will cause problems, you don't have to worry about that, because you can't do anything about it anyway.

You also have to be careful not to return `array_local`, because it will be deallocated when the function returns, since it's allocated in the function stack frame.

Also, the above code is not necessary to copy the array, you could just

```
memcpy(array_local, v, size * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Size is a parameter. He's already making sure the caller specifies the size of the local array.

Comment: I figured as much, but then you should write that `v` must have at least `size` elements. `array_local` automatically does.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a `Variable Length Array`, and they only exist in C99. So as long as your compiler supports the `-c99` compilation flag, and you are using it, the code is valid.

As for whether or not you *should* use it, that depends on how large you expect `size` to be. With stack allocation, you have no protection against allocating too much memory. If you were to use a dynamic allocator, like `malloc`, you could check for a `NULL` return value, whereas with a `VLA`, you will just blow the stack if you ask for too much. If `size` will be small, there is no problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement same thing in other way using dynamic memory allocation and is safe to be implemented:

```
void func(int v[], int size) {
 int *array_local = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) *(array_local + i) = *(v + i);

 /*
 Other stuff...
 */

}
```

Comment: other than 1) in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc (and family) 2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   I've been using this form since first working with C, some 30 years ago.

Comment: Agreed with point 2. But in point 1: if you will not typecast the return of malloc how will you assign the memory to pointer. Compiler will also give error for that. Typecast isn't needed in case of void* only.