# Is dereferencing null pointer valid in sizeof operation

Tags: c, sizeof, dereference, null-pointer

I've come across a snippet of code that to me should crash with a *segmentation fault*, and yet it works without a hitch.  The code in question plus relevant data structure is as follows (with associated comment found right above):

```
typedef struct {
  double length;
  unsigned char nPlaced;
  unsigned char path[0];
}


RouteDefinition* Alloc_RouteDefinition()
{
  // NB: The +nBags*sizeof.. trick "expands" the path[0] array in RouteDefinition
  // to the path[nBags] array
  RouteDefinition *def = NULL;
  return (RouteDefinition*) malloc(sizeof(RouteDefinition) + nBags * sizeof(def->path[0]));
}
```

Why does this work? I gather that the *sizeof* the *char** will resolve to the size of the pointer on the given architecture, but shouldn't it crash and burn while dereferencing a `NULL`-pointer?

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: Joachim's right (+1).  While `sizeof` is likely internal to the compiler, you can often observe this kind of language behaviour in an interesting and tangible form by looking at your Standard library's `offsetof` implementation: it probably takes the address of a data member of a fictitious object made by casting a 0/NULL pointer... that's even closer to the precipice than `sizeof`, but entirely legal.

Comment: `sizeof(def->path[0])` is `1` by definition, so the return statement collapses to the much more readable: `return malloc(sizeof(RouteDefinition) + nBags);`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Why does this work?

This works because *sizeof* is a compile time construct, with the exception of [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) is not evaluated at all. If we look at the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5.3.4` *The sizeof operator* paragraph *2* says(*emphasis mine*):

> [...] The size is determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. **If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated** and the result is an integer constant.

we also see the following example in paragraph *5* which confirms this:

```
double *dp = alloc(sizeof *dp);
       ^^^                ^
                          |                                 
                          This is not the use of uninitialized pointer
```

At compile time the *type* of the expression with be determined in order to compute the result. We can further demonstrate this with the following example:

```
int x = 0 ;
printf("%zu\n", sizeof( x++ ));
```

which won't increment `x`, which is pretty neat.

**Update**

As I note in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21995718/1708801) to [Why does sizeof(x++) not increment x?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8225776/1708801) there is an exception to `sizeof` being a compile time operation and that is when it's operand is a variable length array(*VLA*). Although I did not previously point it out the quote from `6.5.3.4` above does say this.

Although in C11 as opposed to C99 it is unspecified whether `sizeof` is evaluated or not in this case.

Also, note there is a C++ version of this quesiton: [Does not evaluating the expression to which sizeof is applied make it legal to dereference a null or invalid pointer inside sizeof in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28714018/1708801).

Answer (score 10):

The `sizeof` operator is a pure compile-time operation. Nothing is done runtime, which is why it works fine.

By the way, the `path` member is not actually a pointer, so it can't technically be `NULL`.

Comment: The exception to sizeof being compile time is with VLAs.

Answer (score 3):

Stating that `sizeof` is a purely compile-time construct (as currently existing answers do) is not entirely accurate. Since C99, `sizeof` is not a purely compile time construct. The operand of `sizeof` is evaluated at run-time of the operand type is a VLA. The answers posted so far seem to ignore that possibility.

Your code is fine, since it does not involve any VLA. However, something like this can be a different story

```
unsigned n = 10;
int (*a)[n] = NULL; // `a` is a pointer to a VLA 

unsigned i = 0;
sizeof a[i++];      // applying `sizeof` to a VLA
```

According to the C99 standard, the argument of `sizeof` is supposed to be evaluated (i.e. `i` is supposed to get incremented, see https://ideone.com/9Fv6xC). However, I'm not entirely sure that the null-point dereference in `a[0]` is supposed to produce undefined behavior here.

Comment: Are there any cases in which requiring any observable behaviors from the argument of `sizeof` improves the expressiveness of the language?  The only situation in which values computed within `sizeof` could affect its result is when it is applied to a VLA type which is created *within* the `sizeof` expression, and I can think of no reason where allowing that enhances the expressiveness of the language.  Note, btw, that even *typedef* statements can generate executable code!

Comment: @supercat `even typedef statements can generate executable code!`. Could you give an example? Thanks!

Comment: @supercat `even typedef statements can generate executable code!`. Could you give an example? Thanks!

Comment: @pmor: Sure.  Given the declaration `int doSomething(void);`, the block-scope declaration `typedef int silliness[doSomething()];` will invoke `doSomething()`.

Comment: @supercat Indeed, [typedef (pointer to) VLA requires evaluation of the size expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71269041).