# how does it happened that a variable used before it's declared?

Tags: c, initialization, sizeof

I am confused about a function `dictCreate()` in file dict.c of `redis` implementation. I am going to paste the code here:

```
/* Create a new hash table 
 * T = O(1)
 */
dict *dictCreate(dictType *type, void *privDataPtr) {
    dict *d = zmalloc(sizeof(*d));
    _dictInit(d, type, privDataPtr);
    return d;
}
```

variable `d` is used in `zmalloc(sizeof(*d))`, but theoretically it will exist when this line was executed. So my question is how it is possible to use variable `d` before it is declared?

Comment: `d` is already declared :P. you can see that if you rewrite the declaration to `dict* d` which means the same.

Comment: It is using its type, not the value. The type is known in the compile time, so no problem here.

Comment: Very close to  [Is dereferencing null pointer valid in sizeof operation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19785518/1708801).

Comment: BTW, since it is probably does not deserve a question by itself.. What would be preferable way here, `sizeof(*d)` or `sizeof(dict)` and why?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't see any problem with `sizeof(*d)`

Comment: @SouravGhosh No problem at all. I am asking what is better :)

Comment: @EugeneSh.; Its matter of choice. Use either.

Comment: @EugeneSh. [Note-to-self : not to get fancy with non-native language :-)] I tried to mean, here also, `sizeof(*d)` is valid, so I'll go with it. Anyway, it is the preferred way by _most_ (note, I did not say _all_). :-)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I agree with Sourav. `*d` will use the type of the pointer's target, regardless of later change. Not very relevant here, but if you have some lines between the pointer definition and the `malloc`, it might save time thinking which type it has (just put `*` before the name) and avoids errors if you change its type for some reason.

Comment: When I read the question I was wondering *Why not use `sizeof(dict)`* thanks for answering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sizeof` is not a function, it is an operator. It is *executed* (evaluated, to be exact) at compile time, so the *scope*  or *lifetime* you're thinking about `d`, does not apply here. All it needs to know is the **type** of `*d` and that is known at compile time. Sufficient.

Comment: so I know that `sizeof` will execute at compile time, and I want to know something more about the `operator` that will be executed in compile time. thx!

Comment: @whatout: Could you elaborate? "I know that sizeof will execute at compile time ..." contradicts "I want to know something more about the operator ..." actually. Either you know the _operator_ `sizeof`, or you need to know more about it. I presume you know what `sizeof` actually does, as you use it already.

Comment: @Olaf I want to know if that are other operator that will execute at compile time?

Comment: @whatout: Almost any if its operands can be evaluated at compile-time. However, you should read a good C book. Please understand SO is no tutorial or discussion site.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
dict *d = zmalloc(sizeof(*d));
```

is equivalent to

```
dict *d;
d = zmalloc(sizeof(*d));
```

So, `dict *d` declares `d` as a pointer to `dict` type and `= zmalloc(sizeof(*d));` used for initialization. `dict *d = zmalloc(sizeof(*d));` declares `d` as `dict *` and then initializes it in single line.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is wrong, the object exists starting from the `=` sign that starts the initialization. E.g in a initializer you are well allowed to use the address of the object that you are initializing.

Here, in addition, no access to the object itself is needed, `sizeof` only uses the type in this case.