# Is it safe to reference the struct that is being initialized in its initializer?

Tags: c, struct, initialization

Say I've got this type:

```
struct Bitmap
{
    int w, h, *b;
};
```

I am initializing it like this:

```
int w = 7, h = 4;
struct Bitmap bmp = {w, h, calloc(bmp.w * bmp.h, sizeof(*bmp.b))};
```

Is it guaranteed that the compiler will initialize the `struct` sequentially? Can I be sure that by the time the `bmp.b` field is being initialized the `bmp.w` and `bmp.h` fields are already initialized?

Comment: Why is the order important?

Comment: BTW, should make certain the product is calculated using `size_t` math: `bmp.w * bmp.h` --> `(size_t) bmp.w * bmp.h`.

Comment: If the `bmp.b` field is being initialized first, then `bmp.w` and `bmp.h` fields contain garbage at the time of `bmp.b` initialization, and thus thing like `calloc(-542 * 3546, sizeof(*bmp.b))` can occur.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use `calloc(w * h, sizeof(*bmp.b))`?

Comment: Yes I see, use `{w, h, calloc((size_t) w * h, sizeof(*bmp.b))}`

Comment: In this particular case, it should because the compiler would optimize, as the values (7,4) are hardcoded. However, if they are dynamic, then this may  depend on the compiler that shall be used.

Comment: @R_Kapp in real code, I'm using `w + 1` and `h + 1`, which together would result in ugly `calloc((w + 1) * (h + 1), sizeof(*bmp.b))`. And what if the 'w' and 'h' were even more heavily modified?

Comment: Interestingly, even though the answer to each of your questions is affirmative, the code is still broken. Shows how hard it can be to even ask the right question!

Comment: @KerrekSB What do you mean broken? It works just fine if you include the `stdlib` header. And I'm using the C99 standard, not the ancient C89.

Comment: @Xis88: See R Sahu's answer?

Comment: @KerrekSB The affirmative answers have been deleted/edited by their authors.

Comment: @Xis88: I think you misunderstand: The answer to all *your* questions is "yes", as R Sahu explains: Yes, the struct is initialized sequentially, and yes, `bmp.b` is initialized only after `bmp.h` and `bmp.w`. But the important point you're missing is that the evaluation of the initial value for `bmp.b` causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @KerrekSB Do you mean `sizeof(*bmp.b)`? It's not UB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785518/is-dereferencing-null-pointer-valid-in-sizeof-operation

Comment: @Xis88: No, I don't mean that. I mean `calloc(bmp.w * bmp.h, sizeof(*bmp.b))`, which requires two lvalue conversions of possibly uninitialized values. Just as R Sahu describes in his excellent answer.

Comment: @KerrekSB Oh, got it. Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using

```
Bitmap bmp = {w, h, calloc(bmp.w * bmp.h, sizeof(*bmp.b))};
```

is undefined behavior. There are two items in the C99 standard that address this.

> **6.7.8. Initialization**
>
> ...
>
> 19 The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each initializer provided for a particular subobject overriding any previously listed initializer for the same subobject.
>
> ...
>
> 23 The order in which any side effects occur among the initialization list expressions is unspecified.133)

and footnote 133 says:

> In particular, the evaluation order need not be the same as the order of subobject initialization

Together, what they mean is that `bmp.w` will be initialized before `bmp.h`. However, it is possible that `calloc(bmp.w * bmp.h, sizeof(*bmp.b))` is evaluated before `bmp.w` and `bmp.h` are initialized. Hence the undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not safe.

Quoted from N1570 6.7.9 Initialization, emphasis mine:

> 23 The evaluations of the initialization list expressions are
>   indeterminately sequenced with respect to one another and thus **the
>   order in which any side effects occur is unspecified**.

In your code, `calloc(bmp.w * bmp.h, sizeof(*bmp.b))` is not guaranteed to be evaluated before `bmp.w` and `bmp.h` are initialised. This means you have to write

```
int w = 7, h = 4, *b = calloc(w * h, sizeof *b);
struct Bitmap bmp = {w, h, b};
```

or

```
struct Bitmap bmp = {w, h, calloc(w * h, sizeof *b)};
```

Comment: bmp is not defined in the first line, so it has to be `*b = calloc(w * h, sizeof(*b));`