# How to calculate the size of a data member in a structure?

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

I am unable to understand how the `size_1` variable calculates the size of the data member name. Could someone explain `(((struct cheese_msgbuf*)0)->name);` what this line means and does?

```c
#include<stdio.h>
struct cheese_msgbuf {
    long mtype;
    char name[20];
};

int main() {
    /* calculate the size of the data to send: */
    struct cheese_msgbuf mbuf;
    int size;
    int size_1;

    size = sizeof(mbuf.name);
    printf("Using just sizeof operator: %d\n", size);

    /* Or, without a declared variable: */
    size_1 = sizeof(((struct cheese_msgbuf*)0)->name);
    printf("Using pointer: %d\n", size_1);
}
```

Comment: this statement `(struct cheese_msgbuf*)0` is cast the null pointer to your struct type (`struct cheese_msgbuf`).

Comment: sizeof is resolved during compiling not during runtime. So the compiler trusts you when you tell him that at address 0 you have a struct of type cheese_msgbuf.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is dereferencing null pointer valid in sizeof operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785518/is-dereferencing-null-pointer-valid-in-sizeof-operation)

Answer (score 3):

As you probably know, `sizeof` is an operator that returns the size of a specific C symbol. It either requires a variable name  or a type; if the variable name is an array name, it returns the size in bytes of the whole array.

But there's not a *"direct"* way to get the size of a structure field, so here it is the trick you found (I have to say that your code is quite self explanatory):

```
/* Or, without a declared variable: */
size_1 = sizeof(((struct cheese_msgbuf*)0)->name);
```

1. We build a pointer to the structure in which our field is defined: `((struct cheese_msgbuf*)0)`. We just cast the address `0`; we don't need it to be a valid address, we just need to tell the compiler to interpret it as a pointer to `(struct cheese_msgbuf*)`
2. We access the field we need: the char array `name`. We do it just accessing the field in the same way we access it when we have a "real" variable, such as `var->name`.
   In this case we just access `((struct cheese_msgbuf*)0)->name`
3. We pass it to the `sizeof` operator: `sizeof(((struct cheese_msgbuf*)0)->name)`. It will be resolved as **20**

Answer (score 3):

If you had a pointer `p` that pointed to `struct cheese_msgbuf`, you could get the size of the `name` member with `sizeof p->name`.

This code does not have such a pointer, so it constructs one by casting `0` to the type `struct cheese_msgbuf *`. The result is a null pointer.

In code that is executed, it would be improper to evaluate `p->name` when `p` is a null pointer. In many C implementations, it would generate an exception, and it is not defined by the C standard.

However, the `sizeof` operator does not evaluate its operand in this situation. It is a compile-time operation that produces the size of the operand based on its **type**, not upon any actual evaluation of the operand. Since the nominal type of the expression `((struct cheese_msgbuf *) 0)->name` is `char [20]`, the expression `sizeof ((struct cheese_msgbuf *) 0)->name` produces 20.

(If the operand of `sizeof` is a variable length array, the operand is evaluated. Otherwise, the operand is not evaluated.)

Answer (score 2):

#### Casting the NULL pointer

you can look at this code snippet (from your code above):

```
/* Or, without a declared variable: */
size_1 = sizeof(((struct cheese_msgbuf*)0)->name);
printf("Using pointer: %d\n", size_1);
```

This trick is known in `c` programming as casting the NULL ptr. we can look at `null` poiters like: `(void*)0` and in the same way we can cast them to our own defined types like your `struct cheese_msgbuf` type.

compiler helps you to get the `sizeof` `struct cheese_msgbuf` data member `name`,
like below:

```
struct cheese_msgbuf* compiler_temp_pointer = ((struct cheese_msgbuf*)0);
size_t size = sizeof(compiler_temp_pointer->name);
```

hope that this clear things for you

Comment: So, ```struct cheese_msgbuf* compiler_temp_pointer = ((struct cheese_msgbuf*)0);``` is equivalent to ```struct cheese_msgbuf* compiler_temp_pointer = NULL;```?