# Allocating memory with an undefined pointer

Tags: c

I was surprised when `gcc -Wall` compiled this without warning. Is this really legitimate C? What are the risks of writing code like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  int a;
  int b;
} MyStruct;

int main(void) {
  MyStruct *s = malloc(sizeof(*s)); // as opposed to malloc(sizeof(MyStruct))
  s->a = 5;
  printf("%d\n", s->a);
}
```

Comment: It's recommended to do this that to explicitly cast. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Yes, it is valid, and recommended.

Comment: @AntonH it's not about casting the result

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does sizeof(x++) not increment x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225776/why-does-sizeofx-not-increment-x)

Comment: @Deduplicator No, it's not

Comment: Compiling with `clang -S` and looking at the assembly suggests that the compiler determines `*s` is `MyStruct`.

Comment: @icepack: Ok, it does not explain why it is preferable, but the rest it does explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof` is evaluated at compile time.  In this context, `*s` resolves to the type of `*s`, it does not dereference the pointer.

This is the canonical way of using `sizeof`. If you used `sizeof(int)` you leave an opening for an error should the type change (in this case, probably unlikely, but still.)

Comment: Note that given: `void function(const char *n) { short a[atoi(n)]; size_t s = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); …code using a and s… }`, the value of `sizeof(a)` is a run-time computation because `a` is a VLA — variable length array.  (Note that `sizeof(a[0])` is still a compile-time computation, though.)  I make no claims for the quality of the code except for this narrow pedagogical purpose (it is awful).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That's true, VLA's are the exception.

Answer (score 5):

Not only it's legitimate, it's even preferable to the alternative. This way you let the compiler deduce the actual type instead of doing it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Writing

```
MyStruct *s = malloc(sizeof(*s));
```

has exactly the same effect as

```
MyStruct *s = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
```

except that now you only write MyStruct *once*. That is, the object you're allocating has its source *type* determined automatically, which reduces the chances of errors.

For example - it has happened to me - you start with a `MyStruct`. Then you decide you need **also** a different `MyStruct` for different purposes. So you end up with two different structures, `MyStruct` and `AnotherStruct`.

Then you refactor your code and change some variables from `MyStruct` to `AnotherStruct`, and end up with

```
AnotherStruct *s = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
```

which might actually work in several circumstances, or for a long time, *until you make another little and, at that point, completely unrelated change in either structure*. At *that* point your code goes kaboom.

E.g.

```
typedef struct {
        int a;
        int b;
} StructA;

typedef struct {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
} StructB;

int main() {
        // No problem here except wasted space
        StructA *s = malloc(sizeof(StructB));

        // t->c dwells in undefined country
        StructB *t = malloc(sizeof(StructA));
}
```