# Increment operator is not invoked at sizeof(++n) expression

Tags: c++, c, increment, sizeof

In C or C++, increment and decrement operator (`++n`, `--n`) are not performed when it is in a `sizeof()` operator.

```
int n = 100;
int size_int = sizeof(++n);
std::cout<<n;
```

I have written this code and run the program. Of course, I think 101 will be showed for me.
But, `n` was not 101, it was 100.

Why is that?

Comment: sizeof is evaluated at compile time, and that would explain why there is a complexity here the compiler could get wrong, but I would expect the code you posted to write 101 also.

Comment: That's exactly as it should be; `sizeof` doesn't evaluate its argument (unless it's a C variable-length array). Even `sizeof(* (int*) 3);` is valid (and equivalent to `sizeof(int)`).

Comment: @remyabel (just getting to it!) Given the use of `std::cout`, this is obviously C++. Did you know that the two languages can be very different and there might be very different answers (and that you might not care about some of those).

Comment: @remyabel I meant only the comment of "just getting to it" to you, the rest is to the OP. I knew you were either joking about it or griping that people do that :)

Comment: I have edited the question to only refer to C++. The code sample was in C++.  There is already a question for C [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225776/why-does-sizeofx-not-increment-x).

Comment: @haccks Voting to reopen. The suggested duplicate is for C only; and C differs to C++ in this respect.

Comment: Whew, now we have a total havoc in the answers, because a C/C++ answer was wanted. The big question: Which single one will @wizardyk accept.

Comment: @MattMcNabb; True. But this question was initially tagged with C. After closing it, I realized that C tag has been removed. Opened it.

Comment: @MattMcNabb it is not clear to me why you removed the C tag, please see [Retagging C++ questions as C without consulting asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158450/213111) as a reference

Comment: Can you specify whether you want an answer to address C, C++ or both? Currently the question is tagged C++ but you have accepted a C answer. If you want a C answer then the it is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8225776/1708801) and should be reclosed. If you want a C++ answer then the current accepted answer is not correct since it mentions VLA which do not exist in C++.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour The asker used `cout` so he is asking about C++.  If he is also interested in C then he can consult the existing thread .

Comment: @MattMcNabb the problem is that several answers are already C answers and the OP accepted a C answer(*there are no VLAs in C++*) so this question is a mess as it stands now. Honestly the OP should have been more clear but removing the tag was not a good idea after there were already C answers. At this point I am not sure what the right action is though.

Comment: i.e. should we downvote the C answers? They clearly do not cover C++ ...

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour The accepted answer on this is OK as it primarily addresses C++ and adds extra info about C  (a common practice). Only 2501's answer is out of place really. I suggested that he/she delete it from here and repost it on the C thread. None of the current answers on that thread address C11 although I guess you are working on it.

Comment: @MattMcNabb the accepted answer mentioned VLA which is not C++ without a clarification it is a C answer in my eyes.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour that could be fixed with a small edit to the accepted answer . The text in the accepted answer is all correct for C++.

Comment: I'm favouriting this as a bug I only never coded only because I was never imaginative enough to code it!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In C++, the expressions inside `sizeof` is *not* evaluated, <strike>except for C99's [VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)  <sup>as mentioned in comments, since this was earlier tagged for C too</sup></strike>

The `sizeof` operator is calculated at compile time.

Only the *type* of the expression (that is calculated at compile time) is then used by `sizeof`.

From [C++ Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) **§ 5.3.3 Sizeof**

> The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object
>   representation of its operand. The operand is either an expression,
>   which is an *unevaluated* operand (Clause 5), or a parenthesized
>   type-id.

<sup>Some C++ compilers provide VLAs as an extension [as commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403970/increment-operator-is-not-invoked-at-sizeofn-expression-in-c/26404028#comment41479677_26404028).</sup>

Comment: @MattMcNabb Is this the VLA you're talking about ?

Comment: Also, the `()` are not part of the operator's name. Repeat after me, really loud now everybody: `sizeof` is not a function!

Comment: @unwind: I realise this once was a "C/C++" question; you can remove your downvote now.

Comment: @phresnel Earlier OP tagged question with C too

Comment: What would happen if we have an object with an overloaded ++ operator, and a particular usage of ++ increases the size of the object?

Comment: @Ryan Umm, *how* would it do that? Size is a property of the object's *type.*

Answer (score 16):

In C the operand of `sizeof` is not evaluated at except for variable length arrays:

> 6.5.3.4. p2:
>
> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of
>   the operand. The result is an integer. *If the type of the operand is a variable length array
>   type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an
>   integer constant*

If you put `n++` into a variable length array, for example:

```
int n = 1 ; 
sizeof( int(*)[n++] ) ;
```

then it is unspecified if the operand is evaluated.

> 6.7.6.2. p5
>
> If the size is an expression that is not an integer constant expression: if it occurs in a
>   declaration at function prototype scope, it is treated as if it were replaced by *; otherwise,
>   each time it is evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero. The size of each instance
>   of a variable length array type does not change during its lifetime. *Where a size
>   expression is part of the operand of a sizeof operator and changing the value of the
>   size expression would not affect the result of the operator, it is unspecified whether or not
>   the size expression is evaluated*.

Comment: Maybe add 6.7.6.2 p5 (n1570) _Where a size expression is part of the operand of a `sizeof` operator and changing the value of the size expression would not affect the result of the operator, it is unspecified whether or not the size expression is evaluated._ So, e.g. in `int n = 1; sizeof(int (*)[n++])` it is unspecified if `n++` is evaluated.

Comment: suggest moving this answer (incl mafso's comment) to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225776/why-does-sizeofx-not-increment-x)

Answer (score 12):

In C++ `sizeof` doesn't evaluate its operand.

Quote from C++ standard, part `[expr] 5/7` in C++11 or `[expr] 5/8` in C++14:

> In some contexts, unevaluated operands appear (`5.2.8`, `5.3.3`, `5.3.7`, `7.1.6.2`). An unevaluated operand is not evaluated.

Here `5.3.3` refers to `sizeof` (and others are `typeid`, `noexcept` and `decltype`).

C++98 standard doesn't have this paragraph, but anyway in its part `5.3.3 Sizeof` it states essentially the same as newer standards:

> The `sizeof` operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand. The operand is either an expression, which is not evaluated, or a parenthesized *type-id*.

Comment: saying which version of the standard would be nice

Comment: @MattMcNabb OK did it.

Answer (score 11):

If you check out the dis-assembly of:

```
int size_int = sizeof(++n);
```

Then you'll see something like (depending on your compiler):

```
mov dword ptr [size_int],4
```

---

The `sizeof(...)` expression is evaluated during compile-time, and replaced with a constant value.

In the example above, the constant value that the `sizeof(...)` expression is replaced with is 4.