# in the below program why is sizeof returning twice the array size initialized and not just one more byte?

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof

My prgram has no errors I just need an explanation on how the `sizeof` part works here

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char food[5];
    printf("Enter your favorite food:\n");

    //here sizeof doubles array size why??
    fgets(food, sizeof(food+1), stdin); 
    printf("Great choice I love %s\n", food);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "doubles array size" ? how did you measure it, and what is the exact size?

Comment: What if you replace `sizeof(food+1)` with `sizeof(food)+1`?  I never knew `sizeof(food+1)` was even legal - what compiler are you using?

Comment: The type of `food+1` is `char*`. I'm guessing you're on a 64-bit system, so the size of a pointer to `char` is 8 bytes.

Comment: That's a good question.

Answer (score 4):

#### C11: 6.5.3.4:

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. **The size is determined from the type of the operand**.

The type of expression `food + 1` is of *pointer to `char`*. Therefore `sizeof(food+1)` will return the size of pointer.

Comment: food is also a "pointer" as it holds the address of the first element of the array so why sizeof(food) gives 5 and not 8 ? what is the difference between the two types food and food+1 ? @haccks

Comment: @Meninx; As an operand of `sizeof` arrays do not converted to pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It does not double the array size, it gives the size of a pointer. When doing pointer arithmetics with the array `sizeof` considers the argument as a pointer, and gives the size of the argument's type, instead of the size of the array.

And since the argument is a pointer, the value is equivalent to `sizeof(void *)`.

Comment: [Operands of `sizeof` is not evaluated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8225835/2455888). Nitpick: `sizeof` is an *operator*, not a function. So, there is no argument passed to `sizeof`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I was reading and found that `sizeof(variable)` returns the size of the variable, so when I declared `sizeof(food)` the `food` variable takes the size of the character array and then adding one means, the compiler actually doubles the size of the variable by adding one more array of the same size, i.e. allocates space in memory.

```
sizeof(food + 1)
```

Allocates space that is double the size of `food`.

```
sizeof(food)+1
```

Allocates space that is 1-byte more than `food`.

BTW I'm using gcc compiler in Ububtu 14.04

Thank You Guys for helping.