# C - how do I read * and -> together?

Tags: c, pointers, operators, dereference

If I have :

```
char *name; //this is in a struct

*row->name //row is able to get in the struct
```

How do I read *row->name and what is it returning?

I'll link the code I am reading: http://pastebin.com/MvLXkDCz

Comment: It's returning the first element `name` points to. It's like `row->name[0]` which should be used instead to avoid "*confusion*".

Comment: Learn about [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: @iharob if name is not initialized then what would get passed to sizeof(*row->name)?

Comment: @don sizeof is calculated at compile time using only type information.

Comment: @don As others said, [`sizeof` does not "*evaluate*" it's operand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225776/why-does-sizeofx-not-increment-x) so nothing bad would happen, and it's actually a good way of passing the size to `malloc()` for example, for many reasons. For example, if you change the type of `name` you don't need to change *every* `malloc()` and also because it helps you allocate the correct size since it's always correct.

Comment: @don `so 1 byte?` size_t (i.e. unsigned int) to be exact.

Comment: Questions are required to contain all relevant information **in the question itself**! Not a a link, nor as an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the `->` operator is evaluated and then the resulting pointer which is pointing to what `name` points to is dereferenced with `*`. So it's the same as

```
row->name[0]
```

and IMHO this is a better way of expressing the same (*althought sometimes using the indirection operator `*` is clearer*).

Answer (score 0):

The `->` component selection operator has higher precedence than the unary `*` operator, so `*row->name` is parsed as `*(row->name)`; you're dereferencing the `row->name` member.

The same is true for all other postfix<sup>1</sup> operators:

```
*arr[i] == *(arr[i])
*foo()  == *(foo())
*a.p    == *(a.p)
*p++    == *(p++)
*q--    == *(q--)
```

---

1. Component selection operators `.` and `->` are grouped with postfix operators even though they look like infix operators.