# Sizeof operator with variable-length array type

Tags: c, gcc, sizeof, variable-length-array

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof):

> If the type of *expression* is a **variable-length array** type, ***expression*
>   is evaluated** and the size of the array it evaluates to is calculated
>   at run time.

It means: if the type of *expression* is a VLA type, then *expression* is evaluated. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int a[i];
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof(a[i++]));
    printf("%d\n",i); // Here, print 0 instead of 1
    return 0;
}
```

So, according to the reference, here `i` becomes `1`. But, with my GCC compiler, `i` prints as `0`.

See [Wandbox Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/u15UOXihrmkO2Ct6).

Comment: `a[i++]` is not an expression of a VLA type. It's ultimately a subscript expression, and has the type `int`. Beyond that, even for VLA's `a[0]` is a constraint violation.

Comment: The length of the VLA is determined at the time it is defined. In the above code, the length will be 0, so the VLA will have no elements. The size does not change after it has been defined. Also, the length needs to be greater than zero, otherwise it's *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I didn't know C had VLAs. I learned something new unless OP tagged C instead of C++.

Comment: @byxor - It's C++ that doesn't have them other than as compiler extensions (because said compilers also support C).

Comment: try `int a[i][i]; sizeof(a[i++])` that will be sizeof(vla)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does sizeof(x++) not increment x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225776/why-does-sizeofx-not-increment-x)

Comment: it's about sizeof+vla, it's not a duplicate of that question

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all, please note that an array cannot have size zero, be it a VLA or not. So your code invokes undefined behavior.

C11 6.7.6.2/5

> "If the size is an expression that is not an integer constant expression:" /--/ "...each time it is evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero."

---

As for the actual problem, `a[i++]` is of type `int`, not of VLA type.

In order to get the side-effect, you must involve the VLA array type itself, such as `sizeof(a)`. Only then is the operand evaluated for side effects. One example to illustrate this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i=1, j=1;
    int a[i][j];
    int b[1][1];

    (void) sizeof(a[--i]);
    (void) sizeof(b[--j]);
    printf("%d %d", i, j);

    return 0;
}
```

Here `i` ends up as 0 since the first `sizeof` is evaluated because of the VLA, but `j` remains 1 because `--j` was part of a `sizeof` for a regular array.

Comment: Off topic to the original question but any idea why the standard provides a special case for the expressions of type VLA?

Comment: @Ajay Assuming `int a[i];`, expression `sizeof a` must be able to calculate correct result at runtime, because value of `i` is not known at compile time.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Because the size is only set in run-time, so that it cannot necessarily get pre-calculated at compile-time.

Comment: @Lundin, it just requires value of the `sizeof a[--i]` to be a runtime value. There is no need to evaluate the operand. The size if inferred from the type of operand, not from its value

Answer (score 9):

The expression in sizeof in your example is int, and not vla. If it were vla, all would work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 5;
    int a[i][i];
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof(a[--i]));
    printf("%d\n",i); // Here, print 4
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From [C Standards#6.5.3.4p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p2) [*emphasis mine*]

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of the operand. **The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant**.

In the expression:

```
sizeof(a[i++])
```

the `a[i++]` is not VLA but a subscript operator expression resulting in an integer. So, the operand is not evaluated and for the same reason, compiler is giving warning on this statement:

> `warning: expression with side effects has no effect in an unevaluated context`

Answer (score 3):

To take the word of a clone of a normative references for it:

[**6.5.3.4 - The sizeof and _Alignof operators**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4)

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
>   may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
>   determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If
>   the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand
>   is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result
>   is an integer constant.

It would be evaluated, if you fix your example to produce an expression with VLA type, one such way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    int a[5][i];
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof(a[i++]));
    printf("%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

[Prints `2` on the last line](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5839a35591f5551), because `i` is incremented.