# Does gcc automatically perform a mathematical operations on const values during compilation

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization

Lets say we perform

```
malloc(4 * sizeof(int))
```

Now, the number 4 is a constant and from my understanding `sizeof` is actually compile time function (unless you have a variable inside of it).

In this case (considering x86) `sizeof(int)` would also be 4. My question is: will the gcc optimization perform the calculation itself or will the equation be generated in the asm?

Comment: This is low-hanging fruit for a compiler.  The answer is: yes, the compiler will compute this -- it will not be calculated at runtime.

Comment: sizeof is always compile-time except for the very special case of VLA.

Comment: `sizeof` isn't a function, btw, it's a keyword.

Comment: @Shawn [it's an operator](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#1) ;) So one might argue it's a special kind of function.

Comment: Please *pick* *one* programming language. I answered before noticing this. Is this C or C++. There is already one answer that is right in C++ and wrong in C!

Comment: That is the part that confused me because people say that sizeof is a operator, i thought it would be the same for both C and C++. I apologize for confusion but i'm interested what happens in both cases.

Comment: @BranislavBrzak yes, the answer to this *incidentally* happens to be mostly the same in C and C++. But that's not a good excuse!

Comment: Still have a lot to learn, i will keep that in mind.

Comment: [sizeof is evaluated at compile time unless we are dealing with VLA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21995718/1708801) which some compilers support in C++ as an extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called "constant-folding" and yes, it will happen before assembly. Assembly in itself is usually not optimized at all.

Consider the minimal program

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
}
```

We can compile it into assembly with `gcc -S`. On my computer, the resulting assembly says:

```
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    $16, %edi
        call    malloc@PLT
        movl    $0, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

I.e. the only constants you see in there are `16` (`4 * sizeof(int)`), and `0` (the implicit return value from `main()`).

---

Note that in C there is a class of expressions that are called "integer constant expressions" that are supposed to be evaluated at the compilation time. You can use `4 * sizeof(int)` as the size of an array - or even within a `_Static_assert` clause - naturally then it *must* be evaluated during the compilation, but in general case, such as here, the C standard does not require one or the other.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And i know that about assembly, it would be better if i phrased the question "will the operation happen compile or run time".

Comment: @BranislavBrzak that is different question and that *too* has been answered here.