# Size of a function when call sizeof

Tags: c++, sizeof, puts

I have a function as below:

```
int fun()
{
    puts("hello");
    return 10;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d",sizeof(fun()));
    return 0;
}
```

I want to ask why when I call `sizeof(fun())` it just return size of `int`. and why `puts` in func() function don't show out in screen.

Comment: What do you expect `sizeof` to give you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225776/why-does-sizeofx-not-increment-x?rq=1

Comment: Note that the `sizeof` operator returns a value of type `size_t`. The correct `printf` format specifier for `size_t` is e.g. `"%zu"`, and definitely *not* `"%d"`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: sizeof is interpreted at compile time ... it just return the size of the return type of fun, that is int. It does not call fun at all

Comment: *"why when I call sizeof(fun()) it just return size of int"* You didn't ask for the size of `fun`, you asked for the size of the result of calling `fun` with no arguments, and the result is `int`. Size of `fun` would be `sizeof fun` (which doesn't compile, since functions don't have sizes in C++).

Comment: The expression inside `sizeof(...)` is unevaluated context, the function won't be called. It will only evaluate the size of the return type.