# Why does dereferencing a wild or null pointer when passed to malloc not lead to a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc, dereference

These pieces of code cause a segmentation fault:

```c
int *i;
printf("%d\n", *i);
```

```
int *i = NULL;
printf("%d\n", *i);
```

while these do not:

```
int *i;
i = malloc(sizeof *i);
```

```
int *i = NULL;
i = malloc(sizeof *i);
```

In all examples wild and null pointers dereferenced and passed as an argument to a function which should cause a segmentation fault. Why do the examples using malloc not behave as expected and produce a segmentation fault?

Comment: `sizeof` is not a function it's a builtin  operator that returns the size of it's argument. `sizeof *i` is the size of the thing pointed by `i` that is the size of an `int` in your case. There is no dereferencement, and therefore no segfault

Comment: IOW, `sizeof *i` does not dereference `i`.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8225835/898348

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the last two cases involving `sizeof`, the operand of the `sizeof` operator is not actually evaluated.  It is observed for its type and the result is calculated at compile time.

Section 6.5.3.4p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the `sizeof` operator states:

> The `sizeof` operator  yields  the  size  (in  bytes)  of  its  operand,  which  may  be  an expression or the parenthesized name of a type.  The size is determined from the type of the operand.  The result is an integer.  If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; **otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.**

So there is no actual pointer dereference occurring.

Also, there's no guarantee that dereferencing a NULL pointer or an uninitialized pointer will cause a crash.  It's actually [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so it *might* crash, or it might not.

Answer (score 1):

[§ 6.5.3.4 The sizeof operator](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
> expression or the parenthesized name of a type. **The size is determined from the type of
> the operand**. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array
> type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an
> integer constant

Answer (score 1):

> **6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators**
> ...
> 2     The **`sizeof`** operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
> expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of
> the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array
> type, the operand is evaluated; ***otherwise, the operand is not evaluated*** and the result is an
> integer constant.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

Under most circumstances `sizeof` does not evaluate its operand, so nothing gets dereferenced - it only cares about the *type* of the expression `*i`, not its value.