# How to elegantly fix this unused variable warning?

Tags: c, macros, unused-variables

I'm working on some C code that does lot's of error reporting and logging when a `DEBUG` flag is set, which sometimes produces **unused variable** warnings when compiling with the `DEBUG` flag not set.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define CHECK(expr) foo(expr)
#else
#define CHECK(expr)
#endif /* DEBUG */

int x = bar(a, b, c); /* bar has to be called for both DEBUG begin defined and undefined */ 
CHECK(x == SOME_VALUE); /* Produces an "unused variable" warning if DEBUG is undefined
```

Edit: Just a little reminder (not sure if it is of any consequence): the argument for the `CHECK` macro is an **expression, not a single variable**.

**For this pattern, what is the best way to get rid of the unused variable warning?**

What I tried/though of:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
int x = bar(a, b, c);
#else
bar(a, b, c);
#endif
CHECK(x == SOME_VALUE);
```

and then, to avoid writing the call to `bar` (which is more complicated in the actual call) twice:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
int x = 
#endif
bar(a, b, c);
CHECK(x == SOME_VALUE);
```

However, I feel like this is not exactly a clean and readable solution. Is there a better way? Note that for performance reasons the `CHECK(expr)` macro should not produce any code if `DEBUG` is undefined (**EDIT:** and thus, `expr` should not be evaluated).

**Is there a more elegant way than the one I outlined above?**

Comment: @yuhao Any specific reason for removing the `compiler-warning` tag?

Comment: May be you should say : "the CHECK(expr) macro should not produce any code, but expr should still be evaluated, in other words, CHECK(bar(a,b,c) == someval) must result in bar(a,b,c) being called.

Comment: @shodanex: Why should I? The expression `expr` shouldn't be evaluated if `DEBUG` is undefined.

Comment: @mort, i meant you should define wether you want expr to be evaluated or not.

Comment: @shodanex: I edited it for clarity's sake, though I think that it is actually implied by "macro should not produce any code if DEBUG is undefined"

Comment: Note: Rather than `DEBUG`, code could use the standard `NDEBUG` with the opposite logic `#if`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define CHECK(x) x
#else
    #define CHECK(x) ((void)sizeof((void)(x),0))
#endif
```

I think this addresses all of the possible issues :

- `sizeof` ensures that the expression is not evaluated at all, so its side-effects don't happen. That is to be consistent with the usual behaviour of debug-only constructs, such as [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/assert).
- `((x), 0)` uses the comma operator to swallow the actual type of `(x)`. [This is to prevent VLAs from triggering evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31027237/vlas-and-side-effect-in-sizeofs-operand).
- `(void)` explicitly ignores the result of `(x)` and `sizeof` so no "unused value" warning appears.

Comment: While this does work, it's hardly more elegant than the solution I have in the question...

Comment: @mort What do you mean ? Your code is free of `#ifdef`s, and no code is generated at all in release mode. I don't think it gets any better.

Comment: but if you want the side effects ? here CHECK(bar(a,b,c) == SOME_VALUE) won't generate code at all in non debug mode.

Comment: @Quentin: True, but a non-expert will not immediately understand what the `CHECK` macro does and why it requires the use of `sizeof`

Comment: @shodanex If you want side-effects, use Sourav's answer. But that conflicts with the "no code in release mode" requirement from OP. For the record, that's also what `assert` does.

Comment: @mort Why do you care ? Just document what the macro *does*, and all is fine. You could even copy/paste the explanation inside a comment along with it if you so wish.

Comment: your solution only works if you do x = bar(a, b, c); CHECK(x == 0xaa). If someone use your check macros to do CHECK(bar(a,b,c) == 0xaa) then bar is not called, so it is misleading

Comment: @Quentin i misunderstood the poster intent, you were right. standard asset looks like an heisenbug nest to me.

Comment: @Quentin for some reason, i can't change my mind on the vote unless you edit your answer.

Comment: If the expression contains a VLA, part of it very well is evaluated. `sizeof(int[i++])`. Acknowledged, this is a bit artificial, but - some programmers are very creative breaking macros.

Comment: @Olaf I'm out of creativity and [didn't manage to break it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c244b77f43ae70a) -- have I missed something ?

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your question correctly, you can do something like

```
#ifdef DEBUG
.
.
#else
#define CHECK(expr) ((void)(expr))
#endif /* DEBUG */
```

to get rid of the warning.

Comment: @Rémi [This shows the warning](https://ideone.com/zusXaD) and [this does not](https://ideone.com/RtMxV5). Can you show me otherwise?

Comment: Hmmm..anybody upvoting the comment by @remi, can you people show me some code, too? or The DVs on answer and UVs on comment is due to  PEBKAC?

Comment: Caution : while this solves the warning, it also executes the expression (and all side-effects) even in release mode, which the original macro didn't.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: The code is fine and the correct ideom - basically. It just lacks a pair of parentheses around `expr`. As-is it might invoke "unused expression in statement" or similar warning for `CHECK(x)`.

Comment: @Quentin: You are right about the side-effects. But as debug mode should not behave otherwise, such effects should be restricted to error statistics - no effects for the normal code. And this can be achieved by helper functions which are empty/not called for release target. Finally: a dead expression without side-effect will be optimised away by a good compiler.

Answer (score 0):

With this solution there is no need for an intermediate variable.

```
#define DEBUG

#define DOCHECK(a) printf("DOCHECK %d\n", a)

#ifndef DEBUG
#define CHECK(a, b) a
#else
#define CHECK(a, b) do {int x = a; DOCHECK(x == b);} while (0)
#endif

int bar(int x, int y)
{
  return x+y;
}    

int main()
{
  CHECK(bar(2,3), 2+3);
  return 0;
}
```